# .Net Core OData query filter not parsing with special characters like ? &

Tags: .net, parsing, .net-core, filter, odata

In our code we are passing theWebAPi call using OData query filter to the API COntroller like

https://localhost:44372/v1/odata/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx?$select=type_of_secur&$filter=type_of_secur eq 'Ability & ABS'

or

https://localhost:44372/v1/odata/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx?$select=type_of_secur&$filter=type_of_secur in  ('Ability & ABS')

The field is a Enum and we are getting integer value from the Table column , so based on the Text given in the Filter clause it should match with the Table column value with the ENum String and it should return the result.

But if we add special caracters in the filter values we are getting the below error (ie) its not parsing.

**"errors": {
"Invalid request parameters": [
"Invalid OData query '? There is an unterminated string literal at position 37 in 'type_of_secur eq 'Corporate CMOs ?'."
]
},**

For that purpose i tried to implement below code using FilterBinder and replace the special characters by some how but the request is not even parsing, so what can we do. If we are using encoding characters in the filter like **'type_of_secur eq 'Corporate CMOs %26 ABS'**, then it is going inside the **BindConstantNode method inside the CustomFilterBinder class**.

**public class CustomFilterBinder : FilterBinder
{
public override Expression BindConstantNode(Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ConstantNode constantNode)
{
XXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYY
}
}**